# How to correct Conditional WHERE and JOIN sql table request?

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, conditional-statements

I'm trying to select an specific information from a table that depends on the conditions of two other tables. When I try separate conditions work, but when I try to work with two conditions does not.

With this I get the correct data from table:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM commerce_order WHERE m_key = 'total'";
```

And with this I also get the result from table:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM  commerce_order M 
        JOIN commerce_order_items I 
          ON M.item_id = I.item_id 
        JOIN produtcs P 
          ON I.order_id = P.ID 
        WHERE status = 'complete'";
```

but when I try this I don't get any result:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM commerce_order M 
        WHERE m_key = 'total' 
        JOIN commerce_order_items I 
          ON M.item_id = I.item_id 
        JOIN produtcs P 
          ON I.order_id = P.ID 
        WHERE status = 'complete'";`
```

I expected the first code result to be filtered by the second code condition. I know which are the values from the first table that should return, but I don't get any.

Comment: you can't put `WHERE m_key = 'total'` before `JOIN` all your `WHERE`s should go after all your `JOIN`s

Answer (score 0):

You can't put `WHERE m_key = 'total'` before `JOIN` all your `WHERE` clauses should go after all your `JOIN`s:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM commerce_order M  
    JOIN commerce_order_items I 
      ON M.item_id = I.item_id 
    JOIN produtcs P 
      ON I.order_id = P.ID 
    WHERE status = 'complete' AND m_key = 'total'";
```

Comment: The problem is that if I do that I'll be considering m_key to be in produtcs table as status, but m_key is in the first table, wich are the one that I want the values from.